# Why use to fillRect instead of translate?

Tags: html, canvas

I want to know why on the translate that you call translate before the second fillRect with the same coordinates?

Couldn't you just fillRect with another coordinates?

Code:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,50);
ctx.translate(70,70);
ctx.fillRect(100,10,100,40);
```

Comment: Yes, you can just change the fillRect coordinates instead of using .translate.  IMHO, changing the coordinates is less confusing...it certainly requires less processing.

Comment: Because in this case all the translate does is move the rectangle 70 units in the X direction and also 70 units in the Y direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could.  Removing the translation and using `ctx.fillRect(170,80,100,40);` instead would be simpler and have the same result.